# Using sed to Reinstate a User's Password Hash

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell-script, sed

Version information for this question is as follows:

```
root@hypervisor:~# uname -a
Linux hypervisor 4.4.35-1-pve #1 SMP Fri Dec 9 11:09:55 CET 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@hypervisor:~# cat /etc/debian_version
8.9
root@hypervisor:~#
```

Since Linux containers tend to be frequently created / destroyed, I need to come up with a way to preserve user's passwords for their user accounts on these containers.

To this end, I save `/etc/shadow` before destroying a container. When the container is re-deployed, I do the following on the re-created Linux containers:

```
#!/bin/bash

HASH_TO_REPLACE=$(grep testuser /etc/shadow)
HASH_TO_RESTORE=$(grep testuser /root/shadow_SAVE)

echo "HASH_TO_REPLACE: $HASH_TO_REPLACE"
echo "HASH_TO_RESTORE: $HASH_TO_RESTORE"

sed -i "s!$HASH_TO_REPLACE!$HASH_TO_RESTORE!" /etc/shadow
```

This seems to work fine. But there's one thing that concerns me:

It's my understanding that `!` can never appear within a (non-disabled) password hash. So, I've used it as my `sed` delimiter for now. But the possibility that the password could be disabled (in which case `!` would appear in the shadow file) means `!` should not be used as the `sed` delimiter. What other characters are guaranteed to never appear in a password hash and are therefore safe to use as a sed delimiter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following characters are used to encode password hashes in Debian 8 (my use case; this very likely applies quite broadly among modern Linux implementations):

> ./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

Any character not in this set and not an exclamation point (used to represent disabled passwords) may be used as a sed delimiter.